# Append onto current URL with Twig?

Tags: php, twig, slim

I'm currently making a simple file hosting script using Slim, Twig, and PHP. Right now I'm trying to append onto the current URL using Twig but am not sure how to do this. I've tried `/panel/{{ newURL }}` but it always just redirects me to `/panel/newurl`. I need to be able to dynamically update this URL.

For example, if I want to go to `/tests` on `/panel/core/` I need to be able to append that onto the current URL. Does Twig offer a way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up just passing `'url' => $request->getUri()->getPath()` in my view parameters. I think this is a pretty decent method because there are other methods you can call on `getUri()` to get different results depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use Twig to render your paths? I think your application should always be able to resolve the paths, so also let the application itself render them ;-)

If that would help; you can add the parameters of the current request to the path rendering:

```
{{ path('yourpath', app.request.query.all|merge({'myparam': 'value'})) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Built-in parameter in twig {{ app.request.uri.path }}

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to ensure that you've included all route *and* query string parameters in the URL you're appending to.

Here's an example of appending `foo=bar` to the current URL:

```
{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge(app.request.query.all)|merge({'foo': 'bar})) }}
```